# google chrome extension rejected http request

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've prepared chrome extension that was rejected to be published because of some issues (they haven't specified what is wrong exactly). Below message i recieved from them about rejection:

> Your item "[name of extension]" [here some kind of id] is
>   being taken down as it currently violates the section of the Developer
>   Program Policy relating to Malicious Products as its obfuscating a
>   part of code. Per our policies, where possible, make as much of your
>   code visible in the package as you can. If some of your app's logic is
>   hidden and it appears to be suspicious, we may remove it.
>
> To have your item reinstated, please make any necessary changes to
>   ensure:
>   All of the files and code are included in the item’s package. 
>   All code inside the package is human readable (no obfuscated or minified code).
>   Avoid requesting or executing remotely hosted code (including by referencing remote javascript files or executing code obtained by XHR requests).

Most probably they don't like this part of my code

```
$.get('http://mydomain/catalogue/message.php?date=' + today, function() {})
.done(function(responseMessage) {
  chrome.notifications.create(
    'reminder'
    ,{type: 'basic'
      ,title: responseTopic
      ,iconUrl: "small.jpg"
      ,message: responseMessage}
    ,function(notificationId) {});
});
```

This request suppose to answer with a text message to notify the user. Is this a threat? Can javascript be injected this way? If yes, can I strip it somehow?

Comment: Just in case, have you studied the [Developer Program Policies](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/program_policies) entirely, including all linked documents?

Comment: I've read most of it. My extension is about 50 lines of code, so very small and there are not much lines that might have caused rejection.There is a little chance that the only thing I've made wrong was minified jquery, what I've fixed, there is nothing more.

Comment: @cinkciarzzpolski Did you manage to publish your extension back to the store?

Comment: @tube-builder i haven't tried for the second time

Comment: @cinkciarzzpolski I am facing the same issue. Were you able to publish your extension?